# Сравнение датафреймов с помощью matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Есть два датафрейма, один содержит данные о недвижимости вне центра города, другой внутри центра. Столбцы в обоих датафреймах одинаковые price, total_area, rooms, ceiling_height. Все числовые, но в столбце с ценами значения намного больше чем с остальными.
Нужно вывести 4(на каждый столбец) гистограммы со сравнениями значений одного столбца датафрейма с другим
Пробовал добавить столбец с ключом firstDF/secondDF, сгруппировать всё это по ключу и вывести гистограмму найденную где-то в гугле, но не вышло так как значения стоимости очень сильно отличаются от значений других столбцов.

UPD: Извиняюсь что непонятно, я пока что чайник во всех этих делах. Первая картинка: датафрейм(два объединённых) который у меня есть, хочу на выходе иметь 4 отдельных гистограммы как на второй картинке для каждой колонки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А причем ЗНАЧЕНИЯ к гистограмме???  А что такое "гистограммы со сравнением одного столбца с другим", если гистограммы имеют смысл только внутри столбцов??? В общем -  ВОСПОИЗВОДИМЫЙ пример в студию, прямо в текст вашего вопроса - будем думать, что вы имели ввиду и как это можно реализовать. И не забудте также внятно описать, что именно вы хотели-бы получить на выходе, а то пока - ничего не понятно.

Comment: То, что у вас на картинке - это НИКАК не гистограмма. Что у вас по оси Y?  Гистограмма -  это график статистического распределения элементов. А у вас что?   Может, вы просто строите столбиковый график? Хотя что по вертикальной оси - все равно не понятно. Попробуйте использовать общепринятую терминологию. И если вы умеете строить один такой график, то непонятно, что мешает их построить четыре, для каждого из столбцов?